# How to toggle jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, anaglyph-3d

```
$('img').anaglyphImage({
  intensity: 20,
  quality: 0.9
});
```

This codes are making an image anaglyph effect, there's no problem here,
I want to remove this effect to clicking a button and adding this effect again like switch button 3d on/3d off

Thanks..

Comment: Show us more info about your problem...

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery function .toggle funtion for this work. Something like this

```
 $('img').toggle(
     anaglyphImage(){
       intensity: 20 ;
       quality: 0.9 ;
        }
    notanaglyphImage(){
       intensity: 10 ;
        quality: 0.1 ;
   };
```

Search on internet for correct Syntax.
toggle : api.jquery.com/toggle/